# Can visual studio 2013 run on a tablet?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tablet-pc

Lenovo miix 3

http://shopap.lenovo.com/students/au/en/tablets/lenovo/miix-series/miix-3-10-inch/#tab-customize

These are the specs. Ive seen it can run but the thing that pulled my attention is that it comes with win8.1 sst (small screen touch). Anyone tried it on something like that? Will it work?